# relativedelta - Add # of months based on column values

Tags: pandas, relativedelta

I would like to add "exact months" to a start date to a start date in order to calculate an end date and have been playing with relativedelta. I have the following:

```
df1['Start Date'] = ['11/1/2018', '3/15/2019', NaN, '5/15/2019', '2/28/2017', NaN, '10/31/2018']

df1['Months'] = [12.0, 36.0, 15.0, 36.0, 12.0, 9.0, 5.0]
```

df1['Start Date'] is currently datetime64[ns] while df1['Months'] is float64.

The end result should be df1['Start Date'] + .df1['Months'] - 1 day but the relativedelta aspect is important as I'd like to return "exact months." NaN can continue to return NaN.

Here was my attempted calc:

```
df1['End_Date'] = df1['Effective_Date'].apply(lambda x: x + relativedelta(months = df1['Months'].astype(float))) - pd.DateOffset(days = 1)
```

I get the following error that I'm not sure how to resolve:

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I tried the following to no avail:

```
df1['Months'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes, add months by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) per rows by `axis=1` and last subtract one day:

```
df1['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start Date'])

f = lambda x: x['Start Date'] + relativedelta(months = int(x['Months']))
df1['End_Date'] = df1.apply(f, axis=1) - pd.DateOffset(days = 1)
print (df1)
  Start Date  Months   End_Date
0 2018-11-01    12.0 2019-10-31
1 2019-03-15    36.0 2022-03-14
2        NaT    15.0        NaT
3 2019-05-15    36.0 2022-05-14
4 2017-02-28    12.0 2018-02-27
5        NaT     9.0        NaT
6 2018-10-31     5.0 2019-03-30
```